# Do Parquet Metadata Files Need to be Rolled-back?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, parquet

When a Parquet file `data` is written with partitioning on its `date` column we get a directory structure like:

```
/data
    _common_metadata
    _metadata
    _SUCCESS
    /date=1
        part-r-xxx.gzip
        part-r-xxx.gzip
    /date=2
        part-r-xxx.gzip
        part-r-xxx.gzip
```

If the partition `date=2` is deleted without the involvement of Parquet utilities (via the shell or file browser, etc)  do any of the metadata files need to be rolled back to when there was only the partition `date=1`?

Or is it ok to delete partitions at will and rewrite them (or not) later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **DataFrame** there is **no need to roll back** the metadata files.

For example:

You can write your DataFrame to S3

```
df.write.partitionBy("date").parquet("s3n://bucket/folderPath")
```

Then, manually **delete** one of your partitions (date=1 folder in S3) using S3 browser (e.g.  CloudBerry)

Now you can

- **Load** your data and see that the data is still **valid** except the data you had in partition date=1  `sqlContext.read.parquet("s3n://bucket/folderPath").count`
- Or **rewrite** your DataFrame (or any other DataFrame with the same schema) using **append** mode

  ```
  df2.write.mode("append").partitionBy("date").parquet("s3n://bucket/folderPath")
  ```

You can also take a look at this [question](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/6494/do-you-need-a-metadata-file-in-a-parquet-folder-to.html) from databricks forum.